# How to get the Results from the Extended Syntax Check

Tags: abap, rawstring

I want to get the results from the extended checker in SAP. I think I found the table where the results are stored (I think it is slin_cache_res). But the value is stored in a rawstring-format. How can I get the result of the last extended check in a readable format? I need them for further processing-tasks.

Comment: Would it be an option to run the Code Inspector with a variant that only contains the extended check and then extract the Code Inspector results?

Comment: thank you very much. that is a great idea. Now I geht the results from the SCIREST_PS table after I ran the Extended Checker over the code inspector.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would try to use the code inspector for this because it's much more flexible, provides more checks and has something like an API that can be used to run the checks and obtain the results:

```
  DATA: lr_inspection       TYPE REF TO cl_ci_inspection,
        lr_object_set       TYPE REF TO cl_ci_objectset,
        lr_check_variant    TYPE REF TO cl_ci_checkvariant,
        lt_result           TYPE scit_alvlist.

  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <ls_result>    TYPE scir_alvlist.

* create an inspection
  CALL METHOD cl_ci_inspection=>create
    EXPORTING
      p_user              = ''
      p_name              = 'MY_INSPECTION_NAME'
    RECEIVING
      p_ref               = lr_inspection
    EXCEPTIONS
      OTHERS              = 1.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
*   ... error handling ...
  ELSE.

*   load object set
    CALL METHOD cl_ci_objectset=>get_ref
      EXPORTING
        p_objsnam                 = 'MY_OBJECT_SET_NAME'
      RECEIVING
        p_ref                     = lr_object_set
      EXCEPTIONS
        OTHERS                    = 1.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
*     ... error handling ...
    ELSE.

*     load check variant
      CALL METHOD cl_ci_checkvariant=>get_ref
        EXPORTING
          p_user            = ''
          p_name            = 'MY_VARIANT_NAME'
        RECEIVING
          p_ref             = lr_check_variant
        EXCEPTIONS
          OTHERS            = 1.
      IF sy-subrc <> 0.
*       ... error handling ...
      ELSE.

*       assemble inspection
        CALL METHOD lr_inspection->set
          EXPORTING
            p_chkv = lr_check_variant
            p_objs = lr_object_set.
        CALL METHOD lr_inspection->save.

*       run inspection
        CALL METHOD lr_inspection->run
          EXPORTING
            p_howtorun             = 'D' " cl_ci_inspection=>c_run_direct
          EXCEPTIONS
            OTHERS                 = 1.
        IF sy-subrc <> 0.
*         ... error handling ...
        ELSE.

*         get the result list
          CALL METHOD lr_inspection->plain_list
            IMPORTING
              p_list = lt_result.

*         ... do something with the results ...

        ENDIF. " sy-subrc after lr_inspection->run
      ENDIF. " sy-subrc after cl_ci_checkvariant=>get_ref
    ENDIF. " sy-subrc after cl_ci_objectset=>get_ref
  ENDIF. " sy-subrc after cl_ci_inspection=>create
```